# Can I sysprep a bootable VHD without using any virtualization technology?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, vhd, sysprep

I booted from a VHD on my laptop and hoped to sysprep this image, but it didn't let me do it. I got a fatal error during the process. I used the following command: sysprep /generalize /shutdown. My question is it possible at all to sysprep a VHD without any HyperV or virtual PC technology?

Answer (score 1):

Sysprep doesn't care about the underlying technology. It will work on physical or virtual hardware.  The issue that you've run into is probably caused by something else.  Can you provide more details on what errors you have?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. After seeing http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproinstall/thread/8f5002e1-95b4-47bf-b031-4b72b3eb388a I killed the wmpnetwk.exe process and sysprep worked fine

Comment: haha i just ended up here from google and was going to upvote this answer. turns out it was my own >.<